# php sendmail not arriving at destination, not logging errors. how do i force dns lookup for sendmail?

Tags: php, magento, email, sendmail

I host a bunch of websites and one of them is an online flower shop. They use a program called FDL. it basically reads confirmation emails from orders and enters them into their systems. Here's my problem: we had an issue with the sendmail program (the program php uses to send emails) recently so i fixed it. Now, if i try to send email from the command line like so:

```
echo "test email" | sendmail -v xxx.xxx@gmail.com
```

it sends it correctly with the following results:

```
LOG: MAIN
  cwd=/home/flowers_website/public_html 3 args: sendmail -v xxx.xxx@gmail.com
LOG: MAIN
  <= root@xxx.xxx.com U=root P=local S=344
[root@xxx.xxx.com www]# LOG: MAIN
  cwd=/var/spool/exim 4 args: /usr/sbin/exim -v -Mc 1VqQdk-00057z-UG
delivering 1VqQdk-00057z-UG
Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.77.26]:25 ... connected
  SMTP<< 220 mx.google.com ESMTP h5si10940958oed.70 - gsmtp
  SMTP>> EHLO xxx.xxx.com
  SMTP<< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [66.135.44.118]
         250-SIZE 35882577
         250-8BITMIME
         250-STARTTLS
         250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
         250-PIPELINING
         250 CHUNKING
  SMTP>> STARTTLS
  SMTP<< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
  SMTP>> EHLO xxx.xxx.com
  SMTP<< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [66.135.44.118]
         250-SIZE 35882577
         250-8BITMIME
         250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
         250-PIPELINING
         250 CHUNKING
  SMTP>> MAIL FROM:<root@xxx.xxx.com> SIZE=1376
  SMTP>> RCPT TO:<xxx.xxx@gmail.com>
  SMTP>> DATA
  SMTP<< 250 2.1.0 OK h5si10940958oed.70 - gsmtp
  SMTP<< 250 2.1.5 OK h5si10940958oed.70 - gsmtp
  SMTP<< 354  Go ahead h5si10940958oed.70 - gsmtp
  SMTP>> writing message and terminating "."
  SMTP<< 250 2.0.0 OK 1386694713 h5si10940958oed.70 - gsmtp
  SMTP>> QUIT
LOG: MAIN
  => xxx.xxx@gmail.com R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com  
[173.194.77.26] X=UNKNOWN:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 C="250 2.0.0 OK 1386694713     
h5si10940958oed.70 - gsmtp"
LOG: MAIN
  Completed
```

but when i try to send an email to the flowers website, like so:

```
echo "test email" | sendmail -v orders@flowers_website.com
```

i get this result:

```
LOG: MAIN
  cwd=/home/flowers_website/public_html 3 args: sendmail -v orders@flowers_website.com
LOG: MAIN
  <= root@xxx.xxx.com U=root P=local S=346
[root@xxx.xxx.com www]# LOG: MAIN
  cwd=/var/spool/exim 4 args: /usr/sbin/exim -v -Mc 1VqQkE-0005Vc-0s
delivering 1VqQkE-0005Vc-0s
LOG: MAIN
  => orders <orders@flowers_website.com> R=virtual_user T=virtual_userdelivery
LOG: MAIN
  Completed
```

i dont know what to do. it says completed, there are no logs at all from sendmail (i cant even find the log file). ive checked /var/logs/mail.log but that doesnt exist. /var/log/maillog contains logs from dovecot, not sendmail. ive looked EVERYWHERE for the log file and i cant find it anywhere. so my question has 2 parts:

A) how do i turn on logging for sendmail?
and
B) chow do i force DNS lookup for sendmail?

I think dns lookup is the problem. it assumes its on the same server when its not. the domain name points to this server, but bind routes the records to another server, where all website data and everything else is stored. FYI it's not listed in the local-host-names file.

P.S. I also temporarily shut down iptables to make sure it wasnt a firewall issue. it wasnt. it still gave the same results and was never received.

**EDIT**

for reference, no other website on our server is having trouble sending order confirmation via PHP. one of them was having a problem with it but i fixed it yesterday and all the rest fell in line. except this one. i assumed it had something to do with DNS resolving the host name or something.. i dont know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `/var/spool/exim` folder to see if there are mail files in it.

**UPDATE** Also, check for errors the Exim log, in `/var/log/exim_mainlog`. Once the sendmail command hands off to another Exim process to handle message forwarding (as indicated by the presence of `R=virtual_user T=virtual_userdelivery`), you will not see any errors in the sendmail output.

Also, check the MX records for the site (on **both** your server and the authoritative server if they are different).  If they are hosting their mail offsite, you need to make quite sure that cPanel (I see that you are using it by going to sample.example.com) knows that and configures Exim appropriately.

Your server knows that Gmail.com is offsite, and so connects to SMTP.  However, by default, it assumes that sites hosted locally also have their mail on the same server and sends them directly to Exim for local delivery.

I had this exact same problem with my web host when I switched to Google Apps - mail sent by the server was still being queued in Exim.  My host had to do something (since I don't have access to cPanel's WHM, I don't know what) to stop it from doing that.

Comment: i am using cpanel by force. i host my own private website entirely from shell. i normally dont use cpanel but the bosses insist i use it when possible.

also, the flowers website was on one of our servers and transferred to another, but DNS is pointing to the new server. so mail and website are hosted on another server, but they are pointed to by this server.

and FYI, theres no mail in /var/spool/exim. heres the ls:
db
exim-daemon.pid
input
msglog